# Does The Cat ever show any interest in Kristine Kochanski?

Tags: red-dwarf

The Cat loves himself and is desperate for a date. In [Justice](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0684160/?ref_=tt_ch) he even says:

> What a dilemma. Inside this pod is either death or a date. And
> personally, I'm prepared to take the risk.

However, when Kristine joins the crew in Series 7 he doesn't appear to pay her attention (aside from referring to her as Officer Bud Babe).

Is there a reason he doesn't pursue her as diligently as the possibility of Barbara Bellini?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I was initially going to answer he would only be interested in other cats (as seen when he fantasizes in later seasons (10 or 11?) if I remember correctly ), but your points about Barbara Bellini seem to nullify that...Maybe it can be chalked up to him expecting Barbara to be another Cat, despite that being a ridiculous consideration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Kochanski is a religious figure in the cat religion. She's married to Kloister the Idiot and lives with him on Fushal

Comment: @Valorum but Cat doesn't necessarily refer to Lister as Kloister, or recognise him as that

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Hence why I didn't post it as an answer. I was merely making an observation

Comment: @Valorum it seems contradictory to say she's a religious figure but not one if Lister =/= Kloister. But it's a worthwhile point to make.

Comment: Possibly his *idea* of a woman is confronted by an *actual* woman and he can't make the next step? His dating experience has been pretty theoretical so far...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - At the time of Barbara Bellini, I don't think the Cat had met another real woman, if you discount "fakes" like the Genetic Mutant, and characters from "Better Than Life" - Maybe he didn't really consider the differences between a human woman and a cat woman until he started meeting them...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cat seems (initially) to be interested in Kochanski, but evidently loses interest after just a few episodes.

**He's obsessed with her underwear for two episodes.**

> **LISTER:** *I'm not here because I'm a sad and lonely person who's entertained by
> women's underwear spin drying.*
>
> **CAT:** *My god, a g-string!*
>
> **LISTER:** *Where?*
>
> **CAT:** *You missed it...  I swear!  It was black and really, really small.*
>
> <sub><sup>Red Dwarf: Duct Soup</sup></sub>

**He hits on her once, inexpertly.**

> **CAT:** *Lateral trimmers not responding!  Like wrestling in treacle!*
>
> **KOCHANSKI:** *You hear that? Cat says the trimmers are like wrestling in treacle!*
>
> **CAT:** *No, I said they were *down*. Then I asked if you like wrestling in -- It can wait..*
>
> <sub><sup>Red Dwarf: Blue</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

Cat tries to impress Kochanski a number of times in the episode *Ouroboros*, giving her the pet name "Officer Bud-Babe". In the subsequent episode *Duct Soup* he also shows an interest in her underwear.

Kochanski only appears part-way into Season 7, and during most of season 8 is separated from the men in prison, so opportunities to interact directly with Cat are limited. Cat does join in with ogling her along with other women in the episode *Krytie TV*, but all the interest he shows in her seems to be characteristically shallow, and he does not make any advances on her.

The general joke about Cat's personality is that the person he loves the most is *himself*. His feelings about women are usually shallow and his desires are just an extension of his adoration for himself. In a number of episodes, he gets very excited about the *prospect* of having someone else adore him, but it very rarely comes to anything.